# python: Dividing a list of values into a set of lists according to a list of indicators

Tags: python

eg.

```
list = [[245, 187], [69, 32] ,
        [892, 176], [133, 120],
        [161, 26], [62, 95]]
conditionslist2 = [0,1,2,0,0,2]
```

Desired Result

```
list0 = [[ 245  , 187],[133 , 120] ,   [161 , 26]]
list1 = [[ 69 ,  32]]
list2 = [[ 892 , 176],[ 62 , 95]]
```

Comment: and what is the logic? and why all the irrelevant tags??

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you think it didn't work. See ["What Have You Tried?"](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) for an excellent article that you may be interested to read. Thanks.

Comment: so you have a ölist of 6 list with2 elements and you have 6 eleme3nts on your secnd list which determine the new list in which it would enter. so give it a try

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to split the input based on a provided list of indexes in the output.

Don't generate variable names, use a dictionary:

```
lst = [[245, 187], [69, 32] ,
       [892, 176], [133, 120],
       [161, 26], [62, 95]]
conditionslist2 = [0,1,2,0,0,2]

from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for i, sublist in zip(conditionslist2, lst):
    out[f'list{i}'].append(sublist)
    
dict(out)
```

output:

```
{'list0': [[245, 187], [133, 120], [161, 26]],
 'list1': [[69, 32]],
 'list2': [[892, 176], [62, 95]]}
```

Comment: thank you @mozway but i want it by list only

Comment: What do you mean "*by list only*"?

Comment: mean not by dictionary, only using lists ..

Comment: Well you can use a list if you want. Or simply run `list(out.values())`.